# Bash: looping-variable-dependent assignment and reference

Tags: bash, loops

I am working on a project where variables need to be assigned according to number contained in a certain file. I feel it may be pointless to include and explain all the code, so I have reduced the question to one involving a simple example.

```
for ((i=1; i<=3; i++));
do
    align_$i=100_$i
done
```

In this example code, I am getting the following error (among the other 2):

```
line 3: align_1=100_1: command not found
```

so I know my method substitution is working, but it is not recognized as a correct assignment. I am clearly making a simple mistake but really have no clue how to solve this.

A little bit of a different idea: I am having an issue calling the value of variable where the variable is doubly dependent on the looping variable.
So, using the supposed correct output from the example above, if I were in another loop where I need to call align_1's value, but need to do so like

```
for ((i=1; i<=3; i++));
    do something with $align_$i
```

how would I properly do this? Using these variables must be in another loop, otherwise I wouldn't have this problem!

I apologize for a simple question-- Bash is not a strength of mine.

Thank you

Comment: This is arguably a duplicate of our many, many questions on indirect assignment and/or expansion.

Comment: See in particular [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Best Answer: Don't

The need for this can generally be avoided if you use an array (or an *associative* array with non-numeric keys):

```
align=( )
for ((i=1; i<=3; i++)); do
    align[$i]="100_$i"
done
```

### But if you must...

#### On bash 4.3+

A namevar allows full, bidirectional access (both read and write) under an aliased variable name; alias targets can be of any type, including arrays themselves:

```
for ((i=1; i<3; i++)); do
    declare -n align_var="align_$i"
    align_var="100_$i"
    unset -n align_var
done
```

#### On older releases

...and if you *don't* have bash 4.3 or later, use `printf -v`:

```
for ((i=1; i<3; i++)); do
    printf -v "align_$i" %s "100_$i"
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, despite the duplicate question! You're helping a novice Bash programmer find leukemia-linked genes :)